# additional .htaccess in subfolder | mod_rewrite for query parameter

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a little mod_rewrite problem and really need some help.

I need to have a second .htaccess file **in a subfolder** for a project on my domain.

The URL to the project is like:

```
https://example.com/project-name/
```

Now I have a query parameter for which I want to create a nice URL with mod_rewrite.

The URL including the parameter looks like this:

```
https://example.com/project-name/index.php?preset=nameofapreset
```

And I want it to be:

```
https://example.com/project-name/nameofapreset
```

**The important thing:** The mod_rewrite has to work for the current folder only. **Without having any info about the current path**, cause I need to use the file in other folders, too.

That's what I thought should work (cause I am using a similar rewrite rule in another project):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z])/?$ index.php?preset=$1
```

But it doesn't. And all my trials fail.

Any ideas how I can make it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this rule in `/project-name/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?preset=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: It works, thank you so much!! Even without the QSA parameter.